# What to do when a CiviCRM demo site is not working?

Tags: demo-site

I am trying to do some testing on the wordpress demo site but it seems to be down.

http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/membership-page/

I seem to be getting an error when running deduping with the wrong wordpress account being link to the remaining record. I want to be able to test this in the demo before submitting another ticket

Cheers - Phil

Answer (score 1):

The demo site may have been down but is currently working.

Demo sites are periodically reset and I'm not sure if there's any downtime when that happens. In any case if CiviCRM infrastructure like demo sites is not functioning correctly, you can try the [IRC](https://civicrm.org/help) and someone there may be able to assist.

Comment: And/or the Infrastructure channel on the chat site: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/infrastructure